# Why do I get an Ninject InvalidOperation exception after my API Controller has completed its request?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, ninject

I have an MVC4 web app project as part of a larger solution. I also have a test project. I am working with a bunch of code that is not going to be reworked, so I can't always make the changes I would like to make.

The MVC4 web app has "normal" Controllers, and Web API Controllers. We are using the RTM version of the Web API, and not an RC.

I attempted to introduce IoC into the project. Using the NuGet installation technique (as opposed to downloading the DLLs and referencing them directly), I installed:

```
Ninject v3.0.1.10, 
Ninject.MVC3 v3.0.0.6
Ninject.Extensions.Factory v3.0.1.0
Ninject.Web.Common v 3.0.0.7
```

I have no other referenced component in my solution that makes use of Ninject.

Then, following the advice given by Brad Wilson, and his Github Gist https://gist.github.com/2417226,  and similar advice given by Filip W here http://www.strathweb.com/2012/05/using-ninject-with-the-latest-asp-net-web-api-source/, I have implemented a NinjectResolver, and "registered" in with the global configuration.

When I fire up the web app, the default page maps to an `Index` action on the `ProjectController`. This renders a view, which uses Knockout to populate a ViewModel via a call to an `ApiController` action called `ApiProjectController.Get()`.

My `NinjectWebCommon.cs` code looks like this:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics.Contracts;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Http.Dependencies;
using Ninject.Extensions.Factory;
using Ninject.Syntax;
using OfficeWebApp.Utilities;

[assembly: WebActivator.PreApplicationStartMethod(typeof(OfficeWebApp.App_Start.NinjectWebCommon), "Start")]
[assembly: WebActivator.ApplicationShutdownMethodAttribute(typeof(OfficeWebApp.App_Start.NinjectWebCommon), "Stop")]

namespace OfficeWebApp.App_Start
{
    using System;
    using System.Web;

    using Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.DynamicModuleHelper;

    using Ninject;
    using Ninject.Web.Common;

    public static class NinjectWebCommon 
    {
        private static readonly Bootstrapper Bootstrapper = new Bootstrapper();

        /// <summary>
        /// Starts the application
        /// </summary>
        public static void Start() 
        {
            DynamicModuleUtility.RegisterModule(typeof(OnePerRequestHttpModule));
            DynamicModuleUtility.RegisterModule(typeof(NinjectHttpModule));
            Bootstrapper.Initialize(CreateKernel);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Stops the application.
        /// </summary>
        public static void Stop()
        {
            Bootstrapper.ShutDown();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Creates the kernel that will manage your application.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>The created kernel.</returns>
        private static IKernel CreateKernel()
        {
            var kernel = new StandardKernel();
            kernel.Bind<Func<IKernel>>().ToMethod(ctx => () => new Bootstrapper().Kernel);
            kernel.Bind<IHttpModule>().To<HttpApplicationInitializationHttpModule>();

            RegisterServices(kernel);

            GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = new NinjectDependencyResolver(kernel);

            return kernel;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Load your modules or register your services here!
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="kernel">The kernel.</param>
        private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
        {
            kernel.Bind<IDataManagerConnection>().To<DataManagerConnection>().WithConstructorArgument("overriddenConnectionString", string.Empty);
            kernel.Bind<IDataManagerConnectionFactory>().ToFactory();
        }        
    }

    public class NinjectDependencyScope : IDependencyScope
    {
        private IResolutionRoot resolver;

        internal NinjectDependencyScope(IResolutionRoot resolver)
        {
            Contract.Assert(resolver != null);

            this.resolver = resolver;
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            IDisposable disposable = resolver as IDisposable;
            if (disposable != null)
                disposable.Dispose();

            resolver = null;
        }

        public object GetService(Type serviceType)
        {
            if (resolver == null)
                throw new ObjectDisposedException("this", "This scope has already been disposed");

            return resolver.TryGet(serviceType);
        }

        public IEnumerable<object> GetServices(Type serviceType)
        {
            if (resolver == null)
                throw new ObjectDisposedException("this", "This scope has already been disposed");

            return resolver.GetAll(serviceType);
        }
    }

    public class NinjectDependencyResolver : NinjectDependencyScope, IDependencyResolver
    {
        private IKernel kernel;

        public NinjectDependencyResolver(IKernel kernel)
            : base(kernel)
        {
            this.kernel = kernel;
        }

        public IDependencyScope BeginScope()
        {
            return new NinjectDependencyScope(kernel.BeginBlock());
        }
    }
}
```

The `ProjectController` code is:

```
public class ProjectController : Controller
{
    private readonly IDataManagerConnectionFactory _dataManagerConnectionFactory;

    public ProjectController(IDataManagerConnectionFactory dataManagerConnectionFactory)
    {
        _dataManagerConnectionFactory = dataManagerConnectionFactory;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        //TODO:             
        ViewBag.Organisation = "Preview";

        return View();
    }
}
```

... and the `ApiProjectController`:

```
public class ApiProjectController : ApiController
{
    private readonly IDataManagerConnectionFactory _dataManagerConnectionFactory;

    public ProjectsController(IDataManagerConnectionFactory dataManagerConnectionFactory)
    {
        _dataManagerConnectionFactory = dataManagerConnectionFactory;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<ProjectTileModel> Get()
    {
        using (IDataManagerConnection connection = _dataManagerConnectionFactory.Create())
        {
            List<ProjectTileModel> projectViewModels = connection.DataManager.GetProjectInfos()
                                                                             .ToList();
            return projectViewModels;
        }
    }
}
```

After the `ApiProjectController.Get()` action method has comepleted, Ninject throws the following exception at me:

```
Error loading Ninject component ICache
No such component has been registered in the kernel's component container.

Suggestions:
  1) If you have created a custom subclass for KernelBase, ensure that you have properly
     implemented the AddComponents() method.
  2) Ensure that you have not removed the component from the container via a call to RemoveAll().
  3) Ensure you have not accidentally created more than one kernel.
```

The call stack looks like this:

```
Ninject.dll!Ninject.Components.ComponentContainer.Get(System.Type component) Line 160   C#
Ninject.dll!Ninject.Components.ComponentContainer.Get<Ninject.Activation.Caching.ICache>() Line 116 + 0x46 bytes    C#
Ninject.Web.Common.dll!Ninject.Web.Common.OnePerRequestHttpModule.DeactivateInstancesForCurrentHttpRequest.AnonymousMethod__1(Ninject.IKernel kernel) Line 74 + 0x27 bytes  C#
Ninject.dll!Ninject.GlobalKernelRegistration.MapKernels(System.Action<Ninject.IKernel> action) Line 75 + 0xe bytes  C#
Ninject.Web.Common.dll!Ninject.Web.Common.OnePerRequestHttpModule.DeactivateInstancesForCurrentHttpRequest() Line 76    C#
Ninject.Web.Common.dll!Ninject.Web.Common.OnePerRequestHttpModule.Init.AnonymousMethod__0(object o, System.EventArgs e) Line 56 + 0x9 bytes C#
```

This exception is being thrown in the following piece of Ninject code, in the `ComponentContainer.cs` file:

```
        Type implementation = _mappings[component].FirstOrDefault(); // <-- see note below...

        if (implementation == null)
            throw new InvalidOperationException(ExceptionFormatter.NoSuchComponentRegistered(component)); // <-- exception thrown here
```

Note: at the line indicated above, the `_mappings` collection contains exactly one item; the key matches the `Type` we are looking for (`ICache`), but the `Values` member (which is a `List<Type>`) is empty (0 count)

Should I **not** be using the `OnePerRequestHttpModule`? Is there something funny happening because I'm using `.ToFactory()` in my bindings? I don't really know why the `OnePerRequestHttpModule` is calling `DeactivateInstancesForCurrentHttpRequest()` but then Ninject seems to be wanting to get at it's internal cache (maybe??)

What is it that I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I never really got to the bottom of this. I don't know if it is a bug in Ninject, or whether I was simply using it incorrectly. I have, however, worked around my problem by switching IoC Containers to AutoFAC.